# How to convert time input hh;mm;ss to hh:mm:ss

Tags: vb.net

If a user inputs a time of `hh;mm;ss` instead of `hh:mm:ss`, is there a way to convert the semicolon to a colon?

I created a timecode tool to help time videos for an online course. The user copy and pastes the timecode provided from another department, but that other department sometimes doesn't put ":" for the time and they use ";". To make things easier, is there a way to have the program convert the semicolon to a colon?

Heres part of the code, if it helps:

```
Dim span As New TimeSpan
        span = TimeSpan.Parse(txtCurrent.Text) - TimeSpan.Parse(txtPrevious.Text)
        txtdur.Text = span.ToString

Dim span2 As New TimeSpan
        span2 = TimeSpan.Parse(txtOld.Text) + TimeSpan.Parse(txtdur.Text)
        txtNew.Text = span2.ToString
```

The user will provide input for text fields: txtOld, txtPrevious, and txtCurrent.
I want to know if there is a way to convert `";"` to `":"` incase the user inputs the time format `"hh;mm;ss"` instead of `"hh:mm:ss"`.

Comment: So you get the time from user in String format?

Comment: Yes, here is a piece of the code: 

Dim span As New TimeSpan
        span = TimeSpan.Parse(txtCurrent.Text) - TimeSpan.Parse(txtPrevious.Text)
        txtdur.Text = span.ToString

        Dim span2 As New TimeSpan
        span2 = TimeSpan.Parse(txtOld.Text) + TimeSpan.Parse(txtdur.Text)
        txtNew.Text = span2.ToString

The user will put the time for the txtold.text, txtprevious.text and txtcurrent.text

Comment: txtOld.Text.Replace(";",":")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String class in .NET gives you the ability to replace specific characters.

If you're storing the time in a TimeSpan variable, this is one way to do it if your input textbox is called txtTimeInput:

```
Dim tsTime As TimeSpan
TimeSpan.TryParse(txtTimeInput.Text.Replace(";", ":"), tsTime)
```

You can go further and add some validation to the TryParse (it returns a boolean) so you can prompt the user to fix their input.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is the first time using the timespan code, so I wasn't sure how to go about it. This fixed my problem!